# Accessing nested data in Jekyll for loop

Tags: for-loop, yaml, jekyll

I'm having a little bit of a hard time getting my head around accessing some nested data with Jekyll. I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm trying to access data within a `prototypes.yml` file. It's for populating cards on a dashboard. When I run the loop, however, nothing gets returned. My guess is I'm not targeting the `details` correctly, but ultimately I'm at a bit of a loss.

**prototypes.yml**

```
ios:
  details:
    -
      category: "category"
      title: "title"
      desc: "desc"
      author: "Sean"
      update: "12 Feb 2020"

android:
  details:
    -
      category: "category"
      title: "title"
      desc: "desc"
      author: "Sean"
      update: "12 Feb 2020"
```

**HTML**

```
{% for row in site.data.prototypes %}
  {% for detail in row.details %}
  <a href="{{ detail.permalink }}" class="c-card c-card--{{ detail.category }}">
    <h2>{{ detail.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ detail.desc }}</p>
    <span>{{ detail.update }}</span>
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` contains two values, the key (e.g. `ios`) and its value. So you'll need

```
{% for row in site.data.prototypes %}
  {% for detail in row[1].details %}
  <a href="{{ detail.permalink }}" class="c-card c-card--{{ detail.category }}">
    <h2>{{ detail.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ detail.desc }}</p>
    <span>{{ detail.update }}</span>
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```